# Number of representations of an integer as the dot product of integer vectors

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $r_k(n)$ denote the number of solutions in positive integers to the equation: $$n = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + \ldots + a_k b_k.$$

> > What estimates and/or asymptotics are available for 
> >     (1) $r_k(n)$ and (2) the $\ell$-th moments: $\sum_{n \leq x} r_k^{\ell}(n)$?

Clearly when $k=1$ this is just the divisor function and the answers to these questions are well-known and elementary for (1) and (2), at least when $k=1$ and $\ell=1,2$.

I'm interested to know what is the state of the art here and also what can be proven using elementary arguments. I assume one can apply either the circle method or the mass formula as with classical questions about representations by sums of squares and other quadratic forms; however perhaps there is a simpler approach.

Comment: George Andrews, Stacked lattice boxes, Annals of Combinatorics 3 (1999) 115-130, studies the number of solutions of the (loosely related) Diophantine equation, $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_4+\cdots+x_kx_{k+1}=n$.

Comment: Yoichi Motohashi, The binary additive divisor problem, Annales scientifiques de l'E.N.S. 27 (1994) 529-572 discusses $r_2(n)$ (but calls it $D(n)$). That sequences is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A055507

Comment: $r_3(n)$ is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A191829